# event gets called twice during second round of app run

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a quiz app with a score counter. Everything works during the first run, but the score counter gets called twice by an event after answering the 2nd question during the second run (second run meaning I used the 'restart quiz' button in the first execution). It gets called twice, and adds points twice from there on out.
Indicating that the event gets bound twice, i am not sure where or how to prevent it.

```
if (answerIsCorrect) {
  scoreCounter();
  responseMsg = `
    <h2>Correct</h2>
    <p>On to the next.</p>
    <button role='button' type="button" class='button js-button-subsequent'>Submit & Next
    </button>`;
}
```

This is the only place where it gets called throughout the code, and it looks like this:

```
function scoreCounter() {
  scoreCount += 10;
  $(".js-score-counter").text(scoreCount);
}
```

Please check out the [CodePen](https://codepen.io/HelleFl/pen/zjGpbG)

Comment: I think you should `.off('click').on('click')` to make sure you don't bind 2 time

Comment: @TanDuong See this would be the easiest, but i don't think it's best practice. Best practice would likely mean that it doesn't bind twice in the first place

Answer (score 1):

The original code would check the answer as many times as you click on any of the radio button after click the next button.

```
function evalChosenAnswer() {
  $(".js-quizform-questions").on("click", "input[type=radio]", event => {
    console.log($(event.currentTarget))
    let answer = $(event.currentTarget)
      .closest(".css-answers")
      .children("label")
      .text();
    renderFeedback(answer);
  });
}
```

So replace it to the following code, which check the answer only once after click the next button,

```
function evalChosenAnswer() {
  $(".js-quizform-questions").on("click", ".js-button-next", event => {

    // check if answer is right or not when click the next button
    let answer = $(event.currentTarget)              // the next button
                 .siblings()                         // find fieldset
                 .find(".css-answers input:checked") // find checked radio button
                 .siblings()                         // find the label
                 .text();                            // get the text
    renderFeedback(answer);
  });
}
```

and remove the same delegate click handler in `function renderFeedback` from

```
function renderFeedback(answer) {
  $(".js-quizform-questions").on("click", ".js-button-next", () => {
    ... codes ...
  });
}
```

to

```
function renderFeedback(answer) {
  ... codes ...
}
```

```js
console.clear();
const DB = [{
    question: "What is the closest star to our own sun?",
    answers: ["Proxima Centauri", "Our sun", "Betelgeuse", "Sirius "],
    correctAnswer: "Proxima Centauri"
  },
  {
    question: "Which U.S. President made the first telephone call to the moon?",
    answers: [
      "Henry Truman",
      "Richard Nixon",
      "Franklin D. Roosevelt",
      "Jimmy Carter"
    ],
    correctAnswer: "Richard Nixon"
  },
  {
    question: "Betelgeuse and Rigel are the two giant stars in which constellation?",
    answers: ["Andromeda", "Aries", "Virgo", "Orion"],
    correctAnswer: "Orion"
  },
  {
    question: "In our solar system, which planet has the shortest day?",
    answers: ["Earth", "Venus", "Jupiter", "Mercury"],
    correctAnswer: "Jupiter"
  },
  {
    question: "Hale-Bopp is classified as which type of small Solar System body?",
    answers: ["Comet", "Asteroid", "Meteoroid", "Meteor"],
    correctAnswer: "Comet"
  },
  {
    question: "What is the name for the disc-shaped region of icy bodies that extends from Neptune to about 55 astronomical units from the Sun?",
    answers: [
      "Orion's Belt",
      "Copernicus' Belt",
      "Caeser's Belt",
      "Kuiper Belt"
    ],
    correctAnswer: "Kuiper Belt"
  },
  {
    question: "In our solar system which two planets are known as ice giants?",
    answers: [
      "Venus & Mars",
      "Neptune & Pluto",
      "Uranus & Neptune",
      "Jupiter & Uranus"
    ],
    correctAnswer: "Uranus & Neptune"
  },
  {
    question: '"Mare Tranquillitatis" is the Latin name for what feature found on Earth\'s moon?',
    answers: [
      "Sea of Tranquility",
      "Chilled Mahi",
      "Tranquil Mars",
      "Calm horse"
    ],
    correctAnswer: "Sea of Tranquility"
  },
  {
    question: "Who were there first two astronauts that landed on the moon in 1969?",
    answers: [
      'Buzz Lightyear & Lance "Woody" Armstrong',
      "Neil Armstrong & Buzz Aldrin",
      "Tom Aldrin & Neil Diamond",
      "Buzz Adderrall & Neil Aldrin"
    ],
    correctAnswer: "Neil Armstrong & Buzz Aldrin"
  },
  {
    question: "The Great Red Spot is a gigantic storm located on which planet in our solar system?",
    answers: ["Earth", "Mars", "Jupiter", "Venus"],
    correctAnswer: "Jupiter"
  }
];
let scoreCount = 0;
let numberIncr = 0;

function renderIntro() {
  $(".js-quizform-intro").show();
  $(".js-quizform-questions").hide();
  $(".js-feedback-page").hide();
  $(".js-quizform-evaluation").hide();
}

function showNext() {
  $(".js-quizform-submit").on("click", event => {
    $(".js-quizform-intro").hide();
    $(".js-quizform-questions").show();
    $(".js-quizform-questions").html(renderQuestion());
  });
}

function renderQuestion() {
  increaseCount();
  return `
    <h2>${DB[numberIncr - 1].question}</h2>
    <form id='form'>
 <fieldset>
     <div class='css-answers'>
                <input id='answer1' type='radio' name='answer' required>
                <label for='answer1'>${DB[numberIncr - 1].answers[0]}</label>
     </div>
     <div class='css-answers'>
                <input id='answer2' type='radio' name='answer' required>
                <label for='answer2'>${DB[numberIncr - 1].answers[1]}</label>
     </div>
     <div class='css-answers'>
                <input id='answer3' type='radio' name='answer' required>
                <label for='answer3'>${DB[numberIncr - 1].answers[2]}</label>
     </div>
     <div class='css-answers'>
                <input id='answer4' type='radio' name='answer' required>
                <label for='answer4'>${DB[numberIncr - 1].answers[3]}</label>
     </div>
 </fieldset>
 <button role='button' type="button" class='button js-button-next'>Submit & Next</button>
  </form>
  `;
}

function evalChosenAnswer() {
  $(".js-quizform-questions").on("click", ".js-button-next", event => {
  
    // check if answer is right or not when click the next button
    let answer = $(event.currentTarget).siblings().find(".css-answers input:checked").siblings().text();
    renderFeedback(answer);
  });
}

function renderFeedback(answer) {

  $(".js-quizform-questions")
    .empty()
    .hide();
  const answerIsCorrect = checkAnswer(answer);
  let responseMsg = "";
  if (answerIsCorrect) {
    responseMsg = `<h2>Correct</h2>
                <p>On to the next.</p>
                <button role='button' type="button" class='button js-button-subsequent'>Submit & Next</button>`;
    scoreCounter();
  } else {
    responseMsg = `<h2>Incorrect,</h2>
                <p>but the universe has many answers.</p>
                <button role='button' type="button" class='button js-button-subsequent'>Submit & Next</button>`;
  }
  $(".js-feedback-page")
    .show()
    .html(responseMsg);

}

function checkAnswer(answer) {
  return answer === DB[numberIncr - 1].correctAnswer;
}

function scoreCounter() {
  scoreCount += 10;
  $(".js-score-counter").text(scoreCount);
}

function renderSubsequent() {
  $(".js-feedback-page").on("click", ".js-button-subsequent", () => {
    if (numberIncr === 3) {
      $(".js-feedback-page").hide();
      $(".js-quizform-evaluation")
        .show()
        .html(renderScore);
    } else {
      $(".js-feedback-page").hide();
      $(".js-quizform-questions")
        .show()
        .html(renderQuestion);
    }
  });
}

function increaseCount() {
  numberIncr++;
  $(".js-question-counter").text(numberIncr);
}

function renderScore() {
  return `
  <h2>You did it!</h2>
  <h3>Your final score is ${scoreCount}.</h3>
  <p>If you want to try again, click the button below</p>
  <button role='button' type="button" class='button js-button-reload'>Submit & Next</button>
  `;
}

function reload() {
  $(".js-quizform-evaluation").on("click", ".js-button-reload", () => {
    $(".js-question-counter").text(0);
    $(".js-score-counter").text(0);
    scoreCount = 0;
    numberIncr = 0
    renderIntro();
  });
}

function startApp() {
  renderIntro();
  showNext();
  // renderFeedback()
  evalChosenAnswer();
  renderSubsequent();
  reload();
}

$(startApp);
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

header {
  align-items: center;
  background: #eee;
  display: flex;
  height: 70px;
  justify-content: center;
}

.counters {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.quizdiv {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 1.5em 0;
}

.quizform {
  border: 1px solid #e3e3e3;
  padding: 1em 2em;
  width: 50%;
}

.controls {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.button {
  border-radius: 4px;
  border-width: 0;
  outline: none;
  padding: 1em;
}

.js-button-next {
  width: 10em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<main role='main'>
  <div class='counters'>
    <p>Question: <span class='js-question-counter'>0</span> / 10</p>
    <p>Score: <span class="js-score-counter">0</span></p>
  </div>
  <div class="quizdiv">
    <div class="quizform js-quizform-intro">
      <h2>Welcome, Willkommen, Bonjour, Buon giorno, Hola</h2>
      <p>Test your knowledge in everything space-related. Just click the button below and start the 10 question quiz.</p>
      <div class="controls">
        <button role='button' class="button js-quizform-submit">Start Quiz</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="quizform js-quizform-questions"></div>
    <div class="quizform js-feedback-page"></div>
    <div class="quizform js-quizform-evaluation"></div>
  </div>
</main>
```